# How to get textboxes' (On stackpanel) values and put them into array using a loop?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a matrix of textboxes, then I want to input some values in these textboxes. After that by clicking a button below my matrix, program should get values (This is the main problem!) I suppose that I can make it using `foreach UIElement`  but it doesn't work... I'm attaching a screenshot and a code, please correct it!

```
private void vsematrici_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    int selectedIndex = vsematrici.SelectedIndex + 2;
    StackPanel[] v = new StackPanel[selectedIndex];
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndex; i++)
    {
        v[i] = new StackPanel();
        v[i].Name = "matrixpanel" + i;
        v[i].Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        TextBox[] t = new TextBox[selectedIndex];
        for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndex; j++)
        {
            t[j] = new TextBox();
            t[j].Name = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
            t[j].Text = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
            v[i].Children.Add(t[j]);

            Thickness m = t[j].Margin;
            m.Left = 1;
            m.Bottom = 1;
            t[j].Margin = m;

            InputScope scope = new InputScope();
            InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();
            name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber;
            scope.Names.Add(name);
            t[j].InputScope = scope;
        }
        mainpanel.Children.Add(v[i]);

    }
    Button button1 = new Button();
    button1.Content = "Найти определитель";
    button1.Click += Button_Click;
    mainpanel.Children.Add(button1);

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myresult.Text = "After button clicking there should be shown a matrix of texboxes values";

    foreach (UIElement ctrl in mainpanel.Children)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            //There should be a a two-dimensional array that I want to fill with textboxes' values
            //But even this "if" doen't work!!! I don't know why...
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding some `StackPanel` to your `mainPanel` and then you're adding textboxes to that stackPanels.

But here:

```
foreach (UIElement ctrl in mainpanel.Children)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
```

you're trying to find these textboxes as they were children of `mainPanel` - of course you can't find them this way.

So you could change your code according to your logic like this:

```
foreach (UIElement pnl in mainpanel.Children)
{
    if (pnl is StackPanel)
    {
        foreach (UIElement ctrl in (pnl as StackPanel).Children)
        {
             if (ctrl is TextBox)
             {
               // your logic here
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I  make a two-dimensional array and fill it with values of textboxes?

Comment: Вы же из России? :)
Ваш код выдаёт ошибку...
Он почему то не хочет принимать это: pnl.Children
Он выдаёт, что "Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement" не содержит определение для "Children".

Comment: @БогданЛашков Well, in the same manner as usual - get your array size from `vsematrici.SelectedIndex`, create `int[] array = new int[selectedIndex]` (or double, or decimal - I don`t know what exact type do you need), and fill it while iterating over your textboxes.

Comment: @БогданЛашков well, it was quick "pseudocode" just to give you idea. in fact, it should be `(pnl as StackPanel).Children` as UIElement doesn't has that property. Also note - StackOverflow is english speaking resource, and if we will speak Russian here - all this information will be useless for most part of community. So use english, please.

Comment: Wow! Works! Thank you very much! Can you suggest a book for learning C#?
(Of course, Russian book)

Comment: Concerning book... While "asking for recommendation of book" and so on is slightly offtopic at StackOverflow - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) is a great list of C# books. I think that "C# in depth" and "CLR via C#" will be very good start. You can find them in Russian translation too, but I recommend to read originals in English.

Comment: @ AndyKorneyev 
Thanks for recommendations! I'm still trying to fill a two-dimensional array
 using this code
 `for (int i = 0; i < matrixdemension; i++)
                                 for (int j = 0; j < matrixdemension; j++)
                                     mxarr[i, j] = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)ctrl));
                            myresult.Text = "some elements:" + "\n" + mxarr[0, 0] + "\n" + mxarr[0, 1];`
but instead of textbox values it fills every element of array with "Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.TextBox"
But I need values...
How can I Correct it?
Screenshot :http://1drv.ms/1ETPde1

Comment: @БогданЛашков oh.... you should really learn more about C# and .NET ;) At least, this one `mxarr[i, j] = Convert.ToString(((TextBox)ctrl));` should be something like `mxarr[i, j] = (ctrl as TextBox).Text;` if your array is array of strings (I don't know if it so, but if it so - it's strange. How do you suppose to find determinant on string values? Probably it should be array of integers or floats?)

Comment: of course I know, that it should be for example in int32, I've made it in string type only for testing, because I'm lazy to type each time a values in textboxes :D
You helped me a lot, thanks very much, I won't bother you  more )
A have been learning C# only 2 weeks, so I have lots of questions...But I will learn it:)

Comment: @БогданЛашков instead of "thank you" you can just mark question as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This will indicate it was helpful and may help some other.